# How can I move the whole view up when the keyboard pop up? (Swift)

Tags: swift

[image]

The gray box at the bottom is a text view. When I tap the text view, the keyboard will pop up from bottom. However, the text view has been covered by the pop up keyboard.

What functions should I add in order to move up the whole view when the keyboard pops up?

Comment: Have a look to this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Thanks @BoilingLime, it simply works. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To detect when a keyboard shows up you could listen to the `NSNotificationCenter`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: “keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

That will call `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide`. Here you can do what you want with your `UITextfield`

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            //use keyboardSize.height to determine the height of the keyboard and set the height of your textfield accordingly
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    //pull everything down again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Milo says, to do this yourself you register for for keyboard show/hide notifications.

You then need to write code that figures out how much of the screen the keyboard is hiding, and how high on the screen the field in question is located, so you know how much to shift your views.

Once you've done that what you do depends on whether you're using AutoLayout or autoresizing masks (a.k.a. "Struts and springs" style layout.)

I wrote a developer blog post about a project that includes working code for shifting the keyboard. See this link:

http://wareto.com/animating-shapes-using-cashapelayer-and-cabasicanimation

In that post, look for the link titled "Sliding your views to make room for the keyboard" at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 complete solution.**

I use this in all of my projects that need it.

on viewWillAppear register to listen for the keyboard showing/hiding and use the functions below to move the view up and back down.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
}

// stop listening for changes when view is dissappearing
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
}

// listen for keyboard show/show events
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

In my case I have a text field at the bottom which gets hidden by the keyboard so if this is in use then I move the view up

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder {
        view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification: notification)
    }
}

func getKeyboardHeight(notification: Notification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4**

This code is not so perfect but worth a try!

First embed the whole view in a scrollView.

Add this little cute function to your class:

```
@objc func keyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions().rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
        if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            scrollViewBottomConstraint?.constant = 0
        } else {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                let keyboardHeight:Int = Int(keyboardSize.height)
                scrollViewBottomConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
                scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: (scrollViewBottomConstraint?.constant)! / 2), animated: true)
            }
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

.

Add this one to your ViewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

Don't forget to connect bottom constraint of your scrollView to your class (with name: "scrollViewBottomConstraint").